# How to send a Direct Message on twitter using Tweppy Client?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to a send a basic direct message on Twitter, but it isn't recognizing 'create_direct_message'. This is the code I am using:

```
Client.create_direct_message(participant_id = '129593148134547046', text = 'Hello')
```

This is the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'create_direct_message'
```

This is how the tweepy website says how to do it on their website, so I'm not sure why my computer is not recognizing it. Is there some way to update tweepy? Could I be running an old version? Please help!
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#manage-direct-messages

Answer (score 0):

The following is steps to send a direct message using Tweepy.

1. On the [Twitter developer portal](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard) you will need to upgrade your account to elevated.
2. Once elevated access is approved and create your app, then got user authentication settings.
3. Set it to the following:

   - Read and write and Direct message
   - Native App
   - Fill in Callback URL and website URL. (its not used by Tweepy, but must be filled)
4. Going back to the App view select the "Keys and Tokens" tab.
5. Store all the information but you need the following.

   - consumer_key
   - consumer_secret
   - access_token
   - access_token_secret

Once you have that information the following sample code should work (fill in the variables).

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
twitter = tweepy.API(auth)

recipient_id = '129593148134547046' # As per example above.
text = 'hello'

direct_message = api.send_direct_message(recipient_id, text)

print(direct_message.message_create['message_data']['text'])
```

If it works the print will be your message.